# PHP & MYSQL Login System for website, Stuck on User Creation

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to write a User Login System for my website.  I'm running WAMP on my laptop and using Aptana for development.  I've been stuck trying to get a User Creation function to work for about 3 days now.  This function here:

```
function create_new_user($email, $pass, $level){
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jadams', 'root', '');
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO jadams.user VALUES ($email, $pass, $level);";
$db->query($insertQuery);
return TRUE;
}
```

I have rewritten this function several times, using prepared statements and various forms of conditional checks, this is just the simplest one in the hopes of figuring it out.  No matter what I try I cannot get the insertion into the database to work.  I have gotten this login function working by forcibly inserting users through phpMyAdmin:

```
function is_pass_correct($email, $pass){
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jadams', 'root', '');
$email = $db->quote($email);
$selectQuery = "SELECT password FROM jadams.user WHERE email = $email;";
$rows = $db->query($selectQuery);
$db=NULL;
if($rows) {
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if($pass === $row["password"]) {return TRUE;}   //MD5
    }
}
return FALSE;
}
```

The structure of my Database is email varchar(256) not null primary, password varchar(256) not null, access int;  I have also tried the query with and without a semicolon.

Comment: Can you give us the list of fields in your user table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the column names in which to insert the values.

```
"INSERT INTO jadams.user (email, password, level) VALUES ($email, $pass, $level);"
```

Also, since you're using the PDO library consider using prepared statements to escape untrusted data.

```
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO jadams.user (email, password, level) 
                VALUES (:email, :password, :level)";
$db = $conn->prepare($insertQuery);
$db->execute(array(':email'=>$email,
                   ':password'=>$pass,
                    ':level'=>$level));
```

Comment: I was told these were optional as long as you fill in everything correctly, but I modified the code to:
    $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO jadams.user (email, password, access) VALUES ($email, $pass, $level);";

still no luck

Comment: Do you have other columns such as a user_id?

Comment: Well, I had written it once using prepared statements and it didn't work, but I just copied this in worked.  I guess I should have kept the old code for comparison. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error?

It's hard to diagnose without knowing the full DB structure, but at first blush it looks like maybe the columns in that table do not match up with the values you provide.

Technically, the column names are not required, but if you do not supply them then you must have appropriate values for each column in order. If there is a `userID` or other field that you are not setting, that could be the issue.

[From the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

> If you do not specify a list of column names for INSERT ... VALUES or INSERT ... SELECT, values for every column in the table must be provided by the VALUES list or the SELECT statement.

To be on the safe side, I would suggest explicitly setting the column names like so:

```
INSERT INTO 
   jadams.user (email, password, level) 
VALUES ($email, $pass, $level)
```

Personally I prefer the INSERT INTO ... SET syntax. It feels more readable and less prone to mixing up columns.

```
INSERT INTO 
    jadams.user 
SET 
    email = $email, 
    password = $password 
    level = $level
```

Of course, this doesn't get into [parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), [password storage](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php), and a whole host of other issues you'll also want to be thinking about.

It's also possible that the semicolon at the end of your query is causing an issue. I know for the old mysql_* functions the manual explicitly stated that you should **not** have a semicolon at the end of a query. However, there's nothing about that in PDO. I *assume* it's fine to have a semicolon at the end now but I would try removing it and see what happens. (Probably nothing).

Comment: The structure of my Database is email varchar(256) not null primary, password varchar(256) not null, access int

Comment: I do have a lot of other security issues address once I get this working.

Comment: Hmm, the only two things I can think of are a type mismatch, or the semicolon at the end of the query causing a problem.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how do catch errors but without luck.  My structure doesn't really let me return to the screen, although I could write an entirely different file just to test it.

Comment: I assume you also did a var_dump and don't see anything suspicious. Technically I think you have a type-mismatch here (email and password should be quoted) but if you already tried it with parameter binding that would resolve that issue. The fact that it's working in PHPMyAdmin is frustrating.